# Configuring IMAP for php function imap_open(); to work

Tags: php

I want to create a script which could open a gmail account and analyze the mails bodies. I want to use IMAP for reading the mails and opening the gmail account, but I have a problem to configure IMAP for PHP.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete.  What is the problem you are having configuring IMAP?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're compiling php from the sources yourself look for a php_imap module.
E.g. the win32 build from http://windows.php.net/download/ ships with a php_imap.dll that can be "included" via [extension=](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension)php_imap.dll in the php.ini.
Many linux distribution have separate packages for various php modules that can be installed through the distribution's package manager (apt, yum, yast, ...)